# Global assignment within a reactive expression in R Shiny?

Tags: r, null, shiny, variable-assignment

suppose I have a data object that is uploaded by the user:

```
  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
    return(data)
  })
```

And suppose I want to delete columns in the dataset. I want to set it to global assignment so that I can run the UI multiple times and have each effect saved in the object.

```
dataset <- reactive({
    file1 <- data()
    file1[,input$deletecols] <<- NULL
    return(file1)
   }}
})
```

However, when I run this, I get the error:

> invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

What's causing this error? and how can I achieve this effect if global assignment doesn't work?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just a tip from page 35 of "The R inferno": avoid use of  `<<-` and use the `assign` function.

Comment: @SabDeM indeed..thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `reactiveValues()` for this kind of need, because it allows you to create and modify your data at different stages in your app.

Here is an example (not tested):

```
values <- reactiveValues()

observe({
   inFile <- input$file
   if (!(is.null(inFile))){
     values$data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
   }
 })

observe({
  values$data[,input$deletecols] <- NULL
})
```

Comment: thank you @cafe876 this works for me! a quick follow up question if you don't mind: 

`values$data[,input$date] <- as.character(as.Date(values$data[,input$date],format=dateformat))`

this doesn't work within the observe for some reason, the dateformat is derived from a user selected input, but when I run this I just get empty values, whereas when this piece of code was outside of the observe it worked fine. hoping you can shed some light on this, thanks!

Comment: @eyio hard to help without seeing the code in context. My first guess would be that the `dataformat`variable is not defined in the right scope